# Automatic code formatter (Ctrl+K) changes content

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, editor

I've recently noticed a disturbing behavior of the code formatting shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>) that seems to be  completely invalid. It appears that applying <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd> resulted in content change (which was correct logically, but completely defaced the question being asked). Here is the question on SO: [Heap corruption using calloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758965/heap-corruption-using-calloc) . Initially I assumed the edit in revision 3 was incorrect and rolled it back. Later I edited myself by applying <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd> and got the same result and had to change it back manually to the original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the indentation by CTRL-K doing that. It's part of the `*` asterisks in the code being interpreted as italics when the code is *not* indented.

When looking at a strange change in a post, always look at both methods of displaying the difference; if you look at the change in markdown only spaces have been added.

The code really does use `float **` and `sizeof(float*)` but that wasn't *visibile* before adding proper indentation: `PermLaster= (float **) calloc(AntPermLast, sizeof(float*));`; the value between the second `*` and the last `*` in the line was italicised instead.

The code formatting is working entirely correctly here, your edits were wrong. By indenting the code properly it is being displayed as code instead of having it being interpreted as markdown-formatted text. That is why I rolled back your edit.

Comment: In this case the result of `Ctrl+K` should've been `(float ***)`, isn't it so?

Comment: BTW, why have you rolled back to rev. 4? Rev. 5 is better

Comment: @icepack: because you altered the original code, which was only being *displayed* wrong, not logically wrong.

Comment: @icepack: No, please look at the *markdown source* and do *not* change the code when editing that post.

Comment: I see now. This is *extremely confusing*. Actually, we don't know what original content was intended by OP.

Comment: @icepack: We *do*, by looking at the revisions. You could also *ask* the OP by leaving a comment.

Comment: @MarijnPieters I don't see how revisions would help here. The OP may have had the same confusion as me (and it's very likely given him being new).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it contains the technical explanation for the behavior. But there is something very wrong with the markdown rules, IMHO.

Comment: @icepack: Then *don't change the code* but leave a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: @icepack: What is wrong with the markdown rules? If you want to display code and not have it interpreted as having further markup you indent it. If it is *not* indented then two `*` asterisks make text italic. Using `_` underscores has the same effect.

Comment: In an ideal world we wouldn't have to do tons of formatting edits to posts. Unfortunately, we aren't in an ideal world. I would expect that in case of possible side-effects (such as  when combining italics with C pointers) the engine would at least present a warning to the writer with an option to reconsider or choose between 2 possible logical results.

Comment: @icepack: That way lies madness. In python underscores are common, and I am sure there are plenty of other languages that use similar symbols in their syntax. Should Stack Overflow have to know about each and every different programming language? What about the Maths Stack Exchange site? The Tex site? This gets complex *really* fast.